# ListView not filling from array

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to fill a `listview` with the files from a directory. I can get the files put into the array, but can't seem to get them in the `listview`. Here's my code; where am I going wrong?

```
private void getDir(final String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(String.valueOf(dirPath));
    final File[] files = f.listFiles();
    myList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }

    if (files != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            // For testing only ---
            System.out.println("Files --  "+files[i]);
            System.out.println("Files --  "+file);
            // End testing ^^^^^


            if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                }
                else {
                    item.add(file.getName());

                }
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_sendsave, android.R.id.list);
        setListAdapter(fileList);


    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No Files",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

And here is my xml file.

```
<ListView
    android:id = "@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart = "true"
    android:layout_above = "@+id/btnSendSave"
    android:clickable = "true"
    android:focusable = "true"
    android:visibility = "visible" />
```

I need to let you know, everything seems to be doing what it should, but the `listview` won't fill.

In the code, there is `system.out.println(files[i])` that shows the files are being put in the array.

Comment: Sorry, setListAdapter does nothing. It was left over from another block of code I was trying. And the Class is public class GetFile  extends ListActivity but I'm sure that has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I would show the working code.

```
public class ListViewDemo extends ListActivity {
private TextView selection;
private String root;
private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // This is the part I added.
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getPath() + "/hvac/");

    if (dir.exists()) {
        root = new String(String.valueOf(dir));
    }
    else {
        dir.mkdir();
        root = new String(String.valueOf(dir));
    }

    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(String.valueOf(root));
    final File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");

                }
                else {
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            }

        }

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Files", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item));
    selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
                            long id) {
    selection.setText(item.get(position));
}
}
```

It works just fine. Thanks to all that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArrayAdapter` constructor has multiple problems:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_sendsave, android.R.id.list);
```

First, you are not passing in `item`, and so the adapter will be empty.

Second, it is unlikely that `android.R.id.list` is the ID of a `TextView` in the row layout that you are using for the `ListView`.

Third, I suspect that `R.layout.activity_sendsave` is not actually the layout that you want for each `ListView` row.

Try this instead:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
```

This uses a built-in simple row layout for your `ListView`, and it provides your list of words.

Here is an example activity that uses this approach, from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/List):

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.list;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewDemo extends ListActivity {
  private TextView selection;
  private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
          "sit", "amet",
          "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
          "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
          "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
          "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        items));
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can get this to work in my project. I just have to replace the items String values with my file names. Again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You loop through your files and for every valid one you do something like:

```
item.add(file.getName());
```

However, `item` is never used after you do that. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) you should do something like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_sendsave, item);
```

This would utilize the `items` array you have built up.

As an aside, while your debugging method to ensure you're getting the items to go into the list is fine, you really should utilize it *after* the complete list has been built (your `if` clause, for instance, may have had an issue). Then, if you are sure the list is correct, you know that whatever is consuming the list is having an issue - which is what happened here.

Comment: Hi,When I do that, I get this error 'android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView'. For the side note, thank you. It works better after the 'if'.

Comment: Yes, I cleaned and rebuilt the project. Still get the error.

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem? Does your layout expect a `TextView` and it's getting a `ListView`?

Comment: Thanks for trying. You did help my look in the right direction.